# When is it Numberwang?

Tags: 2048-numberwang

I am playing [2048 Numberwang](http://louhuang.com/2048-numberwang/). Sometimes the game proclaims: [image]

Is it possible to know exactly when it is Numberwang?

Comment: I had to watch [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjOZtWZ56lc) to understand the game.

Comment: You should watch all Numberwang episodes to get a better grasp.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"That's Numberwang!" is a random message displayed **10%** of the time during score update if your score for that turn is **greater than 8**:

The relevant code is in `html_actuator.js`:

```
function HTMLActuator() {
    ...
    this.thatsNumberwang  = document.querySelector(".thats-numberwang");
    ...
}
...
HTMLActuator.prototype.updateScore = function (score) {
    ...
    if (Math.random() > 0.9 && score > 8) {
        this.showMessage()
    }
    ...
};
...
HTMLActuator.prototype.showMessage = function (message) {
    message = message || "That's Numberwang!";
    var announce = document.createElement("p");
    announce.classList.add("show-numberwang");
    announce.textContent = message;
    this.thatsNumberwang.appendChild(announce);
};
```

Answer (score 13):

Every turn the site contacts Colosson to determine whether or not it is Numberwang. The result is relayed safely back to the user, to avoid further incident.

Comment: It is possible that the dev overrode `Math.random()` to make the necessary telegraph to Colosson. Since @Feichinger's answer doesn't explicitly specify whether this is the case, this is a feasible answer.

Comment: @fredley Oh you! Tsk!

Answer (score -2):

From the site:

> When two tiles touch, that’s Numberwang!

However, since the proclamation does not happen on every turn, best guess is it, like everything else in that game, is random.

Answer (score -3):

"That's" Numberwang" in all winning scenarios that are not Wangernum

Comment: If you watch the show "That Mitchell and Webb Look", where this game originates from - you'll see that there is an alternate game mode called Wangernum - in which the winning state is, "Wangernum". Therefore all winning state that are not Wangernum - must be Numberwang